# Use WPF with .NET Standard Library

Tags: wpf, .net-core, .net-standard

Is it possible to use WPF within an .NET Standard Class Library or is this to be reserved for .NET Core? If so, is it possible to setup a .NET Core Class Library that uses WPF or does it necessarily have to be a .NET Core App?

Comment: Yes, but only on Windows: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/

Comment: But isn't the blog talking about a .NET Core App rather than a plain Class Library?

Comment: WPF is not part of .NET Standard, so if your class library strictly targets netstandardx.x, please don't use WPF.

Comment: And what about a NET Core Class Library? Would that work or only a NET Core Application?

Comment: WPF project can reference and consume .NET Standard libraries. Full .NET Framework version is a superset of .NET Standard.

Comment: .NET Standard is subset of full .NET Framework, so .NET Standard can not reference/consume full .NET libraries(WPF)

Comment: And again: what is about NET Core Class Libraries? Do they support WPF or only NET Core Applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I got in contact with Microsoft. They were very helpful and provided the following snippet of a `*.csproj` file to me:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

With this, I get a .NET Core class library including WPF. Additionally, I had to remove `App.xaml` and `App.cs`. This was necessary since those contain `<Application>` tags in XAML which aren’t allowed in WPF libraries.